# Magento 2.3.3 - Image URLs are getting double slashes added

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, magento-community, aws, s3

wondering if anyone might be able to point me in the right direction, magento is generating image urls with two slashes for me, for example `promobanners//m/o/modern.jpg` or `//.thumbswysiwyg/social/pinterest.png`

I know I should provide more info or what I've tried but I'm honestly lost on this one, I don't really have much more detail. This is a issue because I migrated the media folder over to AWS S3, the double slashes did not affect a regular server, but it break with S3.

Any suggestions on what to troubleshoot are welcome

Comment: have you checked your backend media URL configuration?

Comment: Yep, it looks correct